# return false not working on click of submit button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Same function is working on other page but here it calls the function ,show alert but still form get submiited and return false not working.....
I am using view razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

and here is my submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="demo-submit-button"/>
```

Thanks so much

```
  $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            //alert($("input[type=radio]:checked").val());
            if ($("input[type=radio]:checked").val() == "True") {
                //Logo Image
                var selectedFile = $('#imgfile').val();
                if (selectedFile == "") {
                    alert('please select valid image logo for marketplace');
                    return false;
                } 
                else {
                    var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'];
                    if ($.inArray($('#imgfile').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
                        alert("You are permited to select only '\n.jpeg','.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.bmp' formats are allowed.");
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                //Screenshots
                if ($('#ssimgfile').val() == "" || $('#ssimgfile1').val() == "" || $('#ssimgfile2').val() == "") {
                    alert('please select valid screenshots for marketplace');
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp'];
                    if ($.inArray($('#ssimgfile').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1 || $.inArray($('#ssimgfile1').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1 || $.inArray($('#ssimgfile2').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
                        alert("You are permited to select only '\n.jpeg','.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.bmp' formats are allowed.");
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: As return false should have the same effect, it will probably be useless, but maybe give event.preventDefault() a try.

Comment: I laready tried e.preventDefault() but no help...what is the other option as i said its running perfectly for other page

Comment: See if any other listener is bound to your form with $_data('form', 'events'); Something else might block.

Comment: thanks everyone for the differewnt solutions

Answer (score 0):

You need to "unset" button default event.

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //Your code is here
});
```

Comment: Another solution - `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`
But I don`t know - is it good to use this method.

Comment: stopImmediatePropagation would only keep higher level listeners to execute (say you have your form is in a div, no listener bound to this div will be executed).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should to unbind submit event in your form. Use like this:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('form').unbind('submit');

    $('form')
        .bind('submit', function () {
            var form = this;
            if ($("form").valid()) {
                $.post('/you/url', $(form).serialize(), function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        //to do something
                    } else {
                        //to do something
                    }
                });
            }

            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer. Why is this *the* answer?

Answer (score 0):

I just change to form submit to submit button click and it worked for me though I don't know what was the issue with form submit.

Here what I change

```
 $('#demo-submit-button').click(function () {
//my code
});
```